# Daily use of the UK airspace - VFR flights

Tags: general-aviation, visual-flight-rules, uk

I am considering flying to the UK this summer with a small airplane. I heard that the **daily use of the airspace** is somewhere published by CAA (or NATS), including the activation of Dangerous / Restricted areas. I would like to be able to visualize them via a dynamic map (like the DABS in Switzerland published by Skyguide)

I am however **unable to find the exact location of the website**. Is there something you can help me with ?

Comment: FWIW I know the CAA and NATS websites pretty well, I also cannot find what you're looking for on either.

Answer (score 4):

No affiliation whatsoever, but if you're considering flying VFR in the UK I strongly suggest you purchase a license for [SkyDemon](https://www.skydemon.aero/).

The annual cost is less than 1 hour flying, and for that you get moving map technology on any phone/tablet, a decent view of the absolute mess that is UK Airspace, as well as exactly what you asked - visualization of all those restricted/danger zones etc.

In addition you get live TAFs/METARs and NOTAMs, reviews of all the airfields by other GA pilots and for a small additional fee some professional airfield plates.

Honestly, there is no way I would fly in the UK (or Europe) without it.

Comment: I completely agree on this, Skydemon's visualizations are extremely useful. You can also pay a small amount to file flight plans automatically.

Comment: You get I think 5 free (VFR) flight plan with each annual subscription

Comment: Oh yes, that's true @Jamiec. I've never needed more than that.

Comment: Many thanks all for your answers. I am currently using ForeFlight which also displays the active NOTAM, however I like to benchmark the tool with the official publications to avoid any surprises. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.